# CListCtrl GetSelectionMark() not return row being selected correctly

Tags: c++, mfc

GetSelectionMark() should return the current selected line, but instead it returns the previous selected item. but using GetNextItem(-1, LVNI_SELECTED)
can get the correct answer.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to adjust your question so that people can answer it better. Provide some code example you were working on and the research you did before for optimal context.

Answer (score 1):

It is a zero based index - therefore the first one is zero, second is number one, ...

> The **zero-based selection mark**, or -1 if there is no selection mark.